# RAM fail in Macbook Pro with attached RAM

Tags: hardware-failure, macbook, macbook-pro

I started hearing 3 successive beeps every 5 seconds, googled about it. It says that RAM failed data integrity test. I looked up for my RAM in board but it is attached to board like in image. What is best solution here to fix this laptop?

[image: Macbook Pro A1398 Board]

Answer (score 2):

Soldered-on RAM is *excessively* difficult to replace with new RAM, even with expensive ($10,000) professional tools like a BGA soldering station.

The two best board-level repair shops I know of -- [Rossmann Repair Group](https://www.rossmanngroup.com/) and [Mendon iPad Rehab](http://mendonipadrehab.com/) -- **do not**, as far as I am aware, perform Macbook Pro RAM replacement for models that have soldered-on RAM.

This is because, while it may be possible in theory to do it with the equipment they have, it is an extremely time-intensive and risky job that is ridiculously easy to mess up with the tiniest imperfection. That type of precision is often solved using machine tools, of course, but they don't own any sort of machine that can *reliably* and somewhat easily replace the RAM on these systems.

Apple won't *actually repair* it for you, either! The best they'll do is take out your old motherboard, and swap another basically-working (but possibly flawed, partially damaged or about to fail) motherboard into your original chassis that's used and from someone else's computer (which unfortunately might have its own problems). Or they'll just send you a different Macbook entirely, and almost certainly *not* a brand-new one.

You are free to check with the two companies I listed above (they are *truly* world-class; you won't find anyone better, and 99% of the other shops you find out there will not even attempt repair, they just swap in a new motherboard like Apple would do) and see if they'll attempt it for you, but I don't think they will.

They *could* quite possibly get you your data off of the SSD, though, if that's also soldered in.

There's also quite a lot of "No, that's not possible" [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157719/can-i-solder-more-memory-into-my-macbook-air).